# How to run dplyr::case_when() iteratively when conditional expressions are stored inside a dataframe column?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rlang

I need to build a table that mutates additional columns based on many rowwise conditions. I'm trying to write the very minimal code needed and therefore settled on a certain way. I store all the conditions inside a table up front, and then draw everything from the table. However, I don't know how to iteratively circle over the conditions in the table when approaching the mutation stage.

### Example

Let's say that I want to classify geometric shapes based on their properties. Instead of first writing out code for creating the properties table and then writing very similar code for the conditions, I can specify it once.

```r
library(tibble)

my_table <- 
  tribble(~shape_id, ~string_of_conditions, ~shape_classification,
        "a", c("n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right == \"TRUE\" & n_of_sides == \"4\" & all_sides_equal == \"FALSE\" & is_curve == \"FALSE\""), "rectangle",
        "b", c("n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right == \"TRUE\" & n_of_sides == \"4\" & all_sides_equal == \"TRUE\" & is_curve == \"FALSE\""), "square",
        "c", c("n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right == \"FALSE\" & n_of_sides == \"4\" & all_sides_equal == \"TRUE\" & is_curve == \"FALSE\""), "rhombus",
        "d", c("n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right == \"FALSE\" & n_of_sides == \"4\" & all_sides_equal == \"FALSE\" & is_curve == \"FALSE\""), "trapezoid",
        "e", c("is_curve == \"TRUE\" & equidistant_from_center == \"TRUE\""), "circle",
        "f", c("is_curve == \"TRUE\" & equidistant_from_center == \"FALSE\""), "ellipse")

my_table
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   shape_id string_of_conditions                               shape_classificat~
#>   <chr>    <chr>                                              <chr>             
#> 1 a        "n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & ~ rectangle         
#> 2 b        "n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & ~ square            
#> 3 c        "n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & ~ rhombus           
#> 4 d        "n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & ~ trapezoid         
#> 5 e        "is_curve == \"TRUE\" & equidistant_from_center =~ circle            
#> 6 f        "is_curve == \"TRUE\" & equidistant_from_center =~ ellipse
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Then I can build the dataset based on `my_table`:

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

convert_to_named_vector <- function(x) {
  gsub("==", "=", x) %>%
    gsub("&", ",", .) %>%
    paste0("c(", ., ")") %>%
    parse_expr(.) %>%
    eval(.)
}

new_data <- 
  my_table %>%
  mutate(as_named_vec = map(.x = string_of_conditions, .f = convert_to_named_vector)) %>%
  pull(as_named_vec) %>%
  bind_rows()

> new_data
## # A tibble: 6 x 7
##   n_of_vertices n_of_angles all_angles_right n_of_sides all_sides_equal is_curve equidistant_from_center
##   <chr>         <chr>       <chr>            <chr>      <chr>           <chr>    <chr>                  
## 1 4             4           TRUE             4          FALSE           FALSE    NA                     
## 2 4             4           TRUE             4          TRUE            FALSE    NA                     
## 3 4             4           FALSE            4          TRUE            FALSE    NA                     
## 4 4             4           FALSE            4          FALSE           FALSE    NA                     
## 5 NA            NA          NA               NA         NA              TRUE     TRUE                   
## 6 NA            NA          NA               NA         NA              TRUE     FALSE
```

So far so good. 
 **Here is my question**: for each row in `new_data`, I want to mutate a new column that will hold the classification label for that row. I want to use `case_when` where the LHS will be based on the condition stored in `my_table["string_of_conditions"]`, and the RHS on the value in `my_table["shape_classification"]`.

How can I iteratively run over `my_table`&`new_data` to do this using `case_when`?

Otherwise, a tedious, ***undesired*** 1-by-1 would be:

```r
cond_shape_a <-
  my_table %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  pull(string_of_conditions) %>%
  parse_expr()

classification_shape_a <-
  my_table %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  pull(shape_classification)

new_data %>%
  mutate(figured_out_shape_class = case_when(!!cond_shape_a ~ classification_shape_a))

## # A tibble: 6 x 8
##   n_of_vertices n_of_angles all_angles_right n_of_sides all_sides_equal is_curve equidistant_from_center figured_out_shape_class
##   <chr>         <chr>       <chr>            <chr>      <chr>           <chr>    <chr>                   <chr>                  
## 1 4             4           TRUE             4          FALSE           FALSE    NA                      rectangle              
## 2 4             4           TRUE             4          TRUE            FALSE    NA                      NA                     
## 3 4             4           FALSE            4          TRUE            FALSE    NA                      NA                     
## 4 4             4           FALSE            4          FALSE           FALSE    NA                      NA                     
## 5 NA            NA          NA               NA         NA              TRUE     TRUE                    NA                     
## 6 NA            NA          NA               NA         NA              TRUE     FALSE                   NA
```

Is there a way to achieve this easily enough using `purrr` maybe?

I'm aware this question might seem silly because I could have simply written out the desired output from the beginning using `tribble`. But in my real data this gets cumbersome very quickly, and I need a programmatic solution.

---

EDIT

---

@Jon Spring added in the comments that I could avoid `case_when()` altogether if I had included `shape_classification` within `string_of_conditions` column instead of a dedicated column.

```r
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

my_table_2 <- 
  tribble(~shape_id, ~string_of_conditions,
        "a", c("n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right == \"TRUE\" & n_of_sides == \"4\" & all_sides_equal == \"FALSE\" & is_curve == \"FALSE\" , shape_classification == \"rectangle\""),
        "b", c("n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right == \"TRUE\" & n_of_sides == \"4\" & all_sides_equal == \"TRUE\" & is_curve == \"FALSE\", shape_classification == \"square\""),
        "c", c("n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right == \"FALSE\" & n_of_sides == \"4\" & all_sides_equal == \"TRUE\" & is_curve == \"FALSE\", shape_classification == \"rhombus\""),
        "d", c("n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right == \"FALSE\" & n_of_sides == \"4\" & all_sides_equal == \"FALSE\" & is_curve == \"FALSE\" , shape_classification == \"trapezoid\""),
        "e", c("is_curve == \"TRUE\" & equidistant_from_center == \"TRUE\", shape_classification == \"circle\""),
        "f", c("is_curve == \"TRUE\" & equidistant_from_center == \"FALSE\", shape_classification == \"ellipse\""))

my_table_2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   shape_id string_of_conditions                                                 
#>   <chr>    <chr>                                                                
#> 1 a        "n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right ==~
#> 2 b        "n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right ==~
#> 3 c        "n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right ==~
#> 4 d        "n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right ==~
#> 5 e        "is_curve == \"TRUE\" & equidistant_from_center == \"TRUE\", shape_c~
#> 6 f        "is_curve == \"TRUE\" & equidistant_from_center == \"FALSE\", shape_~

convert_to_named_vector <- function(x) {
  gsub("==", "=", x) %>%
    gsub("&", ",", .) %>%
    paste0("c(", ., ")") %>%
    parse_expr(.) %>%
    eval(.)
}

new_data_2 <- 
  my_table_2 %>%
  mutate(as_named_vec = map(.x = string_of_conditions, .f = convert_to_named_vector)) %>%
  pull(as_named_vec) %>%
  bind_rows()

new_data_2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 8
#>   n_of_vertices n_of_angles all_angles_right n_of_sides all_sides_equal is_curve
#>   <chr>         <chr>       <chr>            <chr>      <chr>           <chr>   
#> 1 4             4           TRUE             4          FALSE           FALSE   
#> 2 4             4           TRUE             4          TRUE            FALSE   
#> 3 4             4           FALSE            4          TRUE            FALSE   
#> 4 4             4           FALSE            4          FALSE           FALSE   
#> 5 <NA>          <NA>        <NA>             <NA>       <NA>            TRUE    
#> 6 <NA>          <NA>        <NA>             <NA>       <NA>            TRUE    
#> # ... with 2 more variables: shape_classification <chr>,
#> #   equidistant_from_center <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The problem with such solution is that it works fine with simple `shape_classification` outputs such as strings (e.g., "square", "rectangle", etc.), but not scalable if we want `shape_classification` to be complex structures such as lists nesting lists, etc.

In such cases we have to resort to a dedicated column for the output:

```r
library(tibble)

my_table_3 <- 
  tribble(~shape_id, ~string_of_conditions, ~shape_classification,
          "a", c("n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right == \"TRUE\" & n_of_sides == \"4\" & all_sides_equal == \"FALSE\" & is_curve == \"FALSE\""), list(list(shape_name = "rectangle", shape_aspects = tribble(~aspect, ~value,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "type_of_geometry", "Euclidean plane geometry",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "sum_of_angles", "360",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "other_names", "oblong"))),
          "b", c("n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right == \"TRUE\" & n_of_sides == \"4\" & all_sides_equal == \"TRUE\" & is_curve == \"FALSE\""), list(list(shape_name = "square", shape_aspects = tribble(~aspect, ~value,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "type_of_geometry", "Euclidean plane geometry",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "sum_of_angles", "360",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "n_of_diagonals", "2"))),
          "c", c("n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right == \"FALSE\" & n_of_sides == \"4\" & all_sides_equal == \"TRUE\" & is_curve == \"FALSE\""), list(list(shape_name = "rhombus", shape_aspects = tribble(~aspect, ~value,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "type_of_geometry", "Euclidean plane geometry",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "plural_form", "rhombi"))),
          "d", c("n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & all_angles_right == \"FALSE\" & n_of_sides == \"4\" & all_sides_equal == \"FALSE\" & is_curve == \"FALSE\""), list(list(shape_name = "trapezoid", shape_aspects = tribble(~aspect, ~value,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "sum_of_angles", "360",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "n_of_diagonals", "2"))),
          "e", c("is_curve == \"TRUE\" & equidistant_from_center == \"TRUE\""), list(c("circle")),
          "f", c("is_curve == \"TRUE\" & equidistant_from_center == \"FALSE\""), list(c("ellipse")))

my_table_3
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   shape_id string_of_conditions                               shape_classificat~
#>   <chr>    <chr>                                              <list>            
#> 1 a        "n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & ~ <list [1]>        
#> 2 b        "n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & ~ <list [1]>        
#> 3 c        "n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & ~ <list [1]>        
#> 4 d        "n_of_vertices == \"4\" & n_of_angles == \"4\" & ~ <list [1]>        
#> 5 e        "is_curve == \"TRUE\" & equidistant_from_center =~ <list [1]>        
#> 6 f        "is_curve == \"TRUE\" & equidistant_from_center =~ <list [1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the motivation to use this kind of approach. Why couldn't you create a lookup table that looks like `new_data` but with the addition of the shape_classification, and join to that?

Comment: Not sure I understand your suggestion. Do you mean that once `new_data` has been created (using the code I showed), *then* create another lookup table?

Comment: @JonSpring I'm more than happy to see other approaches to this problem. It's likely that my approach is over-complicating.

Comment: It seems like `my_table` is a lookup table with your conditions (coded in a compact way) and the associated classifications. Then `new_data` cleverly expands the conditions into a structured table, but without the classifications. If you added the classifications column, you'd have a useful lookup table; if you had a list of conditions, you could join them to that lookup table using the conditions as keys, and you'd get back the classification.

Comment: Ha! That's funny. I didn't see that. So basically this becomes just a way to set up a data frame in a rowwise fashion. But this reminds me of my original motivation: in my real data, my `shape_classification` are in fact complex structures such as nested lists. It'd be a nightmare to spell them out as strings (let alone the nasty backslashes)... Such nightmare is alleviated if they get a dedicated column, hence why `shape_classification` is separate from the rest.

Comment: @JonSpring, I've edited the post to demonstrate the problem when `shape_classification` takes a more complex structure than simple string.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
bind_cols(my_table, new_data) %>% 
  transmute(tmp = map2(string_of_conditions,
                       shape_classification,  ~  
         case_when(eval(parse_expr(.x)) ~ .y))) %>% 
  pull(tmp) %>%
  reduce(coalesce) %>% 
  bind_cols(new_data, figured_out_shape_class = .)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
#  n_of_vertices n_of_angles all_angles_right n_of_sides all_sides_equal is_curve equidistant_from_center figured_out_shape_class
#  <chr>         <chr>       <chr>            <chr>      <chr>           <chr>    <chr>                   <chr>                  
#1 4             4           TRUE             4          FALSE           FALSE    <NA>                    rectangle              
#2 4             4           TRUE             4          TRUE            FALSE    <NA>                    square                 
#3 4             4           FALSE            4          TRUE            FALSE    <NA>                    rhombus                
#4 4             4           FALSE            4          FALSE           FALSE    <NA>                    trapezoid              
#5 <NA>          <NA>        <NA>             <NA>       <NA>            TRUE     TRUE                    circle                 
#6 <NA>          <NA>        <NA>             <NA>       <NA>            TRUE     FALSE                   ellipse
```

Comment: Thanks! It's almost what I had in my mind. I wonder -- is there a way to avoid `bind_cols()`? Meaning, could we rely on `map2(string_of_conditions, shape_classification, ~ case_when(eval(parse_expr(.x)) ~ .y))` *independently* from the order of rows of `new_data`? After all, when using `case_when()` in general, the order of statements inside `case_when()` doesn't matter as long as the conditions are mutually exclusive, and that's the situation here.